# User answered their own question - Does it "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, triage

Just got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16140729) review task: a user that wrote a good explanation (about a subject I don't know enough about, so I skipped).

In the comments, other users tell the OP to edit the question and add the answer, and he says he will.

What should have I done?

- Currently, it doesn't "Looks OK", as it needs excessive editing by the OP.
- It isn't "Unsalvageable", as it's informative and clear.
- Although it "Requires Editing", the editing should be done by the OP, together with an answer.

Again, in this particular case, I just skipped, but what should I do next time?

Comment: IMHO it does not look OK, it looks like a blog post.  They might be able to split it into a Q&A though but as is I would go with too broad or unclear.

Comment: I would assume unsalvageable. It can't be salvaged by the people that would see it if you clicked Looks OK or Requires Edting.

Comment: *It isn't "Unsalvageable", as it's informative and clear.* That's not what Unsalvageable means in the Triage queue. Unsalvageable means that the community (anyone other than the OP) can't edit the question to fix it. Basically, what you stated in your third bullet proves it's unsalvageable. Check out the [Guide for Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue)

Comment: Wow! Has the user who actually goes around vandalising questions for the test reviews finally been unearthed?

Comment: @AndrewMorton User is only 2 days old so I doubt it.

Comment: @TylerH I guess you've been lucky with the bizarreness of your review questions :)

Comment: I did a quick look and couldn't find anything in help - is there a standard for what is acceptable as a user name and does this user's name qualify? (Read backward if you aren't catching it.)

Answer (score 3):

What should you have done or what should you do next time? I don't particularly like telling people what they should and should not do unless I'm in some sort of parental relationship with them, but I thought I'd take a stab at reading the question as if it were me tasked with reviewing it, to see what I would do.

I don't know about the technologies the OP mentions, but I do know the OP makes a lot of assumptions as they explain:

> In a programming language a function typically return integer value to
>   denote success/failure state. Zero is typically treated as success and
>   non-zero is treated as failure.

It becomes clear as the post progresses that they are actually talking about C++, but even then they are still making assumptions. This tells me it needs editing.

The OP then proceeds to converse with the reader in a blog post way about their discovery process for arriving at the answer to their broad question,

> How do i effectively handle errors thrown by ITKs in Teamcenter server
>   customization?"

That answer is effectively, "Don't use the return value of 0 for success, and non-zero for failure; use the language's built-in exception handling (try / catch in this case)."

To me it seems that, though I know nothing about Teamcenter, I know enough about programming in a few languages to realize that what they are really trying to do is say, "Hey, cool! Using a language's built-in exception handling works really well for handling errors!" in a pseudo-question format. The OP said in the comments on the question that they tried to find the answer on SO, but couldn't find it, then when they discovered the answer, they wanted to share. I would submit that the OP didn't find the answer on SO because SO isn't a tutorial site, nor is it a learn-to-program site. The answer the OP discovered is pretty basic for someone who has a background in Computer Science, or for someone who has years of experience with programming.

If the OP had actually asked the question and let the SO community share their knowledge, the OP might have had a good Q&A (or might have been referred to other questions about exception handling in C++). So, in my opinion, the post, as is, belongs on a blog. If edited, the real question isn't the question asked. I wouldn't want to be responsible for editing it, because it wouldn't look much like the OP's original question, and the OP would likely wonder what happened to all his wonderful explanation.

What have I done here? I have reduced the post to its essence: what is the OP trying to say, why are they saying it, why do they take so long to get there, and how could it be shortened?

So, I would suggest next time, try to do that: reduce the post to its essential parts.

Comment: "who has a background in Computer Science, or for someone who has years of experience with programming" lets be honest, we've met CS graduates and year long programmers that don't know how to correctly design a strategy of failures handling.

Comment: @Braiam True, there are those who don't quite get how to handle failures (or who don't ever consider that their code could fail). Perhaps I should have said "a solid background"?