# How to handle answers posted as questions

Tags: discussion, answers, triage, not-an-answer

Recently I was reviewing some questions in the triage queue and I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648223/how-to-regenerate-azure-storage-key-for-classic-and-arm-using-rest-api) question. If you read the "question", you will see that there is no question there. The author even explains in the comments that he wanted to share his knowledge and he didn't intend to ask a question.

Based on the fact that there is no question in the post above (even the author agrees with it) I decided to flag the question with "Unclear what you're asking". 
Today I noticed that my flag was disputed.

So I want to ask, how should we handle cases like this one?

Comment: Point the user to https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and explain that they should edit their post to be a question. If the user doesn't respond, post the answer yourself and make a (suggested) edit to the question.

Comment: Some user already suggested that in the comments but OP has not responded to the comment yet.

Comment: Your flag was (automatically) disputed, because the Triage outcome looks as follows: Looks OK × 3, Requires Editing × 2, Unsalvageable × 2. IMHO it should have been Unsalvageable × 3, because only the OP knows their original question that led to the provided "answer".

Comment: Page not found for "this" question

Comment: @JosephDoggie It's still there, just deleted. You need 10k rep to see it.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377598/educating-new-users-not-to-ask-questions-in-the-answers

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349264/user-answered-their-own-question-does-it-looks-ok

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a reviewer, your course of action is to triage the question as unsalvageable, and when asked provide "unclear what you are asking" as the close reason. The main issue with this question, as you've pointed out, is the fact that *there is no question statement*. Requires Editing implies that *somebody else* could fill in the question on behalf of the asker, but that's not something that we can do. Only the asker is in a position to fill in the question, and as with any other question the question their solution is intended to answer must meet all our rules.

I can understand if the two Requires Editing reviewers misunderstood that option as it's very confusing, but I'm going to go pay the three Looks OK reviewers a visit now...

Comment: Maybe the "looks OK"ers thought it was an answer rather than a question.

Comment: Indeed, I often find it unobvious whether it's an answer or a question presented to me in the review UI.

Comment: This is true *for the example question*, but I can certainly imagine cases where the problem to be solved would be immediately obvious from the post. Imagine a question post that reads largely like a well written blog about a specific problem, for example. Wouldn't it be better to move the content to an answer (maybe CW) and turn the question post into an actual question in that case, rather than completely discard the author's work? (Assuming it's not a duplicate or something, of course.)

Comment: @jpmc26: Triaging a question as unsalvageable (not a fan of the label tbh) doesn't discard the author's work. It resolves the question to be closed, not deleted. It's up to the author to fill in their question themself. It's not the community's job to fabricate a question for them when one hasn't been provided. When one *has* been provided, the author should be notified so they can do it themself and reap all the rep rewards that self-answering would normally entitle them to, *failing which* it would be appropriate for someone else to step in and post a wiki answer and clean up the question.

Comment: @Ruslan: Well, that's confusing and annoying then. It would be worth posting a feature request to improve the UI in this area.

Comment: May 2021, I can't see 'unsalvageable' flag (e.g.: for triaging this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707510/push-notification-firebase-to-app-from-web-using-php-correct-answer-for-ios-a )

Comment: @Kristian: Good, that means they removed it. They replaced it with "flag", which forces you think about what the question should be flagged as. If it *shouldn't* be flagged, then the question wasn't unsalvageable.

Comment: @BoltClock then how should I handle such post in May 2021?